# Use induction to prove the following: $1! + 2! + .... + n! \le (n + 1)!$

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

Use induction to prove the following:
$1! + 2! + .... + n! < (n + 1)!$

Base case: 
$n = 1$

$1! < 2!$ true

Inductive step:
Assume that $1! + 2! + .... + k! \le  (k + 1)!$ is true

let $n = k + 1$

$1! + 2! + .... + (k + 1)! < (k + 2)!$

$1! + 2! + .... + k! + (k + 1)! < (k + 2)!$

$1! + 2! + .... + k! + (k + 1)! < (k + 2)!$

$(k + 1)! + (k + 1)! < (k + 2)!$

$2(k + 1)! < (k + 2)!$

$2(k + 1)(k)(k - 1).. < (k + 2)(k + 1)(k)(k - 1)....$

$2 < (k + 2)$   the right is always bigger for k are non negative integer.

Comment: I see a lot of exclamation marks but no question marks. What is your question?

Comment: Am I doing the induction correctly?

Comment: Do you mean $\leq$ in the title?

Comment: You seem to have the right general ideas, but there are some issues.  (1) Base case should be $n=1$ (as noted by D. Poole).  (2) Also you seem to have concluded that $2\le k+2$, which should not be where you end.  You want to conclude $1!+...+(k+1)!<(k+2)!$.  I.e. the proof part of your argument is backwards.  Work from a known truth to your goal.

Comment: You did the work backwards, I would say. Your work is all there but not written in the traditional way for induction.

Comment: Wow I am not sure why someone downvoted this. There is absolutely no reason for it as the OP stated his/her work (which was mostly correct but awkwardly presented).

Comment: Although this doesn't use induction, we have $1!+2!+\cdots+n! \le n!+n!+\cdots+n! = n \cdot n! < (n+1) \cdot n! = (n+1)!$.

Answer (score 8):

You have all the right pieces, but it's pretty sloppy. Here's a cleaned up version.

---

We will prove by induction on $n \in \mathbb N$ that:

> $$
> 1! + 2! + \cdots + n! < (n + 1)! \tag{$\star$}
> $$

**Base Case:** Notice that $(\star)$ holds for $n = 1$, since:
$$
1! = 1 < 2 = (1 + 1)!
$$
**Inductive Step:** Assume that $(\star)$ holds for $n = k \geq 1$.

It remains to prove that $(\star)$ holds for $n = k + 1 \geq 2$. Indeed, observe that:
\begin{align*}
1! + 2! + \cdots + (k + 1)!
&= (1! + 2! + \cdots + k!) + (k + 1)! \\
&< (k + 1)! + (k + 1)! &\text{by the inductive hypothesis} \\
&= 2(k + 1)! \\
&= (0 + 2)(k + 1)! \\
&< (k + 2)(k + 1)! &\text{since } k \geq 1 > 0 \\
&= (k + 2)!
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$